# How to prove this integral in terms of gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

> Show that
>   $$\Gamma\left(\frac12+x\right) \Gamma\left(\frac12-x\right) = \frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi x)}$$

### My approach

$$\Gamma\left(x+\frac12\right) = \frac{(2x!) \sqrt\pi}{2^{2x}x!}$$

I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

> **In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576), I proved using only real analysis  the [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties)**
>
> $$\Gamma(1-y)\Gamma(y)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi y)} \tag 1$$

---

Letting $x=y-1/2$ in $(1)$, we see that

$$\Gamma\left(\frac12+x\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac12-x\right)=\Gamma\left(y\right)\,\Gamma\left(1-y\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi y)}=\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Euler's reflection formula says that $$\Gamma(z) \cdot \Gamma(1-z)= \frac \pi {\sin(\pi z)}$$

Let $z=\frac 12+x$. Then:

$$\Gamma\left(\frac 12+x\right) \cdot \Gamma \left(\frac 12-x\right)= \dfrac {\pi}{\sin\left(\pi (\frac 12+x)\right)}= \dfrac{\pi}{  \cos(\pi  x)}$$

Comment: Just like mine... ;-))