# Using differentiation under integral sign, find the value of $\int_{0}^{1} \frac {x^{\alpha } + x^{-\alpha} -2}{(1-x) \ln(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Using differentiation under integral sign, find the value of $\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac {x^{\alpha } + x^{-\alpha} -2}{(1-x) \ln(x)} dx$

**EDIT**:My Attempt after P. Lawrence's comment:

The given integral is : $\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac {x^{\alpha } + x^{-\alpha} -2}{(1-x) \ln(x)} dx$.
Here , $\alpha $ is the parameter so we let:
$$F(\alpha )=\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac {x^{\alpha } + x^{-\alpha} -2}{(1-x) \ln(x)} dx$$
Differentiating both sides wrt $\alpha $
$$\dfrac {dF(\alpha )}{d\alpha }=\dfrac {d}{d\alpha} \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac {x^{\alpha } + x^{-\alpha} -2}{(1-x) \ln(x)} dx$$
By Leibnitz Theorem:
$$\dfrac {dF(\alpha) }{d\alpha} = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac {x^{\alpha}\ln(x)-x^{-\alpha}\ln(x)}{(1-x)\ln(x)} dx$$
$$\dfrac {dF(\alpha )}{d\alpha }=\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac {x^{\alpha} - x^{-\alpha}}{1-x} dx$$

Comment: It belongs to the etiquette of this site that you show your attempts. Also, what is $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Start by calling the given expression F(alpha) and finding F ' (alpha), which is a simpler integral. That integral, together with an initial value of F(alpha), would enable you to find F(alpha) in general.

Comment: @P.Lawrence, Please find the edited version. Did you mean to proceed that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the integral $f(\alpha)$, differentiating, and using $(1-x)^{-1} = \sum x^k$ for $|x| < 1$, we have

\begin{aligned} \displaystyle f'(\alpha)  &= \int_0^1 \frac{x^\alpha-x^{-\alpha}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x  = \int_0^1 (x^\alpha-x^{-\alpha}) \sum_{k \ge 0}x^k \,\mathrm{d}x \\& \overset{\text{D.C.T}}= \sum_{k \ge 0} \int_0^1 (x^{k+\alpha}-x^{k-\alpha}) \,\,\mathrm{d}x  = \sum_{ k \ge 0} \left[\frac{1}{k+\alpha+1}- \frac{1}{k-\alpha+1}\right] \\& = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-(k+1)^2}  = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-k^2}=\pi  \cot(\pi \alpha)-\frac{1}{\alpha }. \end{aligned}

Where the last step is the [cotangent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1)  $\displaystyle \pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z}+2z \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{1}{z^2-n^2}.$

Thus $\displaystyle f'(\alpha) = \pi \cot(\pi \alpha)-\frac{1}{\alpha }$, hence $\displaystyle f(\alpha) = \log \left(\frac{\sin  \pi \alpha }{\alpha }\right)+k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

We know from the integral that  $f(0) = 0$ and from our antiderivative that $f(\alpha) \to k+\log(\pi)$ as $\alpha \to 0$. Therefore $k = - \log(\pi)$ hence $$\displaystyle f(\alpha) = \log \left(\frac{\sin  \pi \alpha }{\pi \alpha }\right).$$

Comment: How is $\pi cot(\pi z)=....$?

Comment: @pi-π that's the cotangent series. I added a link.

Comment: How did you write the second step of $f'(\alpha )$?

Comment: @pi-π That's just the geometric series $(1-x)^{-1} = \sum x^k$.

Answer (score 1):

**After OP's work, Here $H_x=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^x-1}{x-1} dt$ are the well known Harmonic numcers. Like $H_n=1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...+1/n$**

$$\frac{dF(a)}{da}=-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^a-x^{-a}}{x-1} dx= -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(x^a-1)-(x^{-a}-1)}{x-1} dx=- H_a+H_{-a}$$
Then 
$$F(a)=\int (-H_a+H_{-a}) da =-\ln\Gamma(1+a)-\ln\Gamma(1-a)+C$$
We have used $\int H_x dx=\gamma+\ln \Gamma(1+x).$
As $F(0)=0 \implies C=0.$
Hence the required summation is finite if $0<a<1$ and it is given by
$$S=-[\ln \Gamma(1+a)+\ln\Gamma(1-a) =-\ln[ \Gamma(1-a) \Gamma(1+a)]=\ln \frac{\sin \pi a}{\pi a}$$
Here we have use $\Gamma(1-z) \Gamma(1+z)=\frac{\pi z}{\sin \pi z}$
For Harmonic numbers one may see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Since the correct answer is $F(\alpha)=\ln\frac{\sin\pi\alpha}{\pi\alpha}$, your answer checks out.

Comment: @user5713492, How did you get that?

Comment: @user5713492 I answer reduces to the form you mention using the properties of $Gamma$ functions. You may see my edit now.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc What is $H_a$?

Comment: @pi-$\pi$ $\int H_x dx=\gamma+ \ln\Gamma(1+z)$ is crucial to my answer.. Also I have now written the answer u=in terms of the expected form. Thanks for yiur question.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc $\int H_x dx=\gamma + \ln \Gamma (1+z)$ Is this a formula? And what is $z$?

Comment: @pi-$\pi$ I have given a ref.harmonic numbers. You may get this in Matematica also that $\int H_x dx=\gamma+\ln \Gamma(1+x)$

Comment: I recalled from [a post by @MarkViola](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1913576/316404) that he developed a Fourier series for $$\cos\alpha x=\frac{\sin\pi\alpha}{\pi}\left(\frac1{\alpha}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac1{\alpha+k}+\frac1{\alpha-k}\right)\cos kx\right)$$ 
This is the series you get in NoName's solution with $x=\pi$, which is similar to mine. The current answer checks, taking into account the [reflection formula for the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).